# How do I override Ctrl+Shift+0 (zero) for WinForms RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, richtextbox, shortcut

For my subclassed `RichTextBox` class, I can capture, suppress the default behaviour of and re-purpose Ctrl+Shift+#, as long as # is between 1 and 9.  For Ctrl+Shift+0, I can't.  I have experimented with `ProcessCmdKey` in the form class and `onKeyDown` and `PreProcessMessage` in the control class.

Here is sample code meant for the control class that should suppress Ctrl+Shift+0 but does not:

```
public override bool PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg)
{
    bool cancel = false;
    int vKeyCode = (int)msg.WParam;

    if(msg.Msg == WinApi.WM_KEYDOWN)
    {
        bool ctrlDown = (WinApi.GetKeyState(Keys.ControlKey) & (1 << 16)) == (1 << 16);
        bool altDown = (WinApi.GetKeyState(Keys.Alt) & (1 << 16)) == (1 << 16);
        bool shiftDown = (WinApi.GetKeyState(Keys.ShiftKey) & (1 << 16)) == (1 << 16);

        if(ctrlDown && shiftDown && vKeyCode == (int)Keys.D0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Cancel!");
            cancel = true;
        }
    }

    return cancel ? true : base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
}
```

However, changing `Keys.D0` to `Keys.D1` shows that the sample otherwise works.

If it's a clue, the default behaviour of the `RichTextBox`, in response to Ctrl+Shift+0, is to change the font.  I went hunting for documentation that mentions this as a built-in shortcut but I didn't find anything (maybe I'm not using the correct search terms).

How should I detect Ctrl+Shift+0 so that I can suppress the default behaviour and write my own?

Comment: Have you tried handling the keypresses in the form's PreviewKeyDown event?

Comment: A sad news for you, I've tried even the `PreFilterMessage` at `application-level` and the `Control + Shift + D0` seems to be `blocked` BUT it effect still applies, it's hard to change this behavior, you can however perform your own code BUT the default behavior is hardly suppressed.

Comment: PreviewKeyDown seems to produce the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tries, I've found out how to actually suppress the `Ctrl + Shift + D0`. However the new problem was even tougher, the `Ctrl + Shift + D0` was suppressed OK but the `beep sound` was generated when releasing the `Ctrl and Shift`, that's so annoying because you said you wanted to **override** these keys combination not **discard** it. So the `beep sound` should not be generated.

After searching much with a hope there was some `style` to apply to `RichTextBox` to prevent the `beep sound` or some message to discard resulting in suppressing the `beep sound` but there are not any such things. I were almost disappointed and intended to let your question **unanswered** forever. I didn't want to add the answer which just partially solved your problem. However it was luckily that I tried `sending some key` instead of the discarded `0 key` to `consume` the keys combination and make the `keys combination` **valid** so no `beep sound` would be generated. Here is the entire code for you, note that we have to use some `global low-level keyboard hook` here, as I said the Application-level message filter also couldn't help:

```
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int hookType, KeyboardLowLevelProc proc, IntPtr moduleHandle, int threadID);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string moduleName);

    public struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public Keys key;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr extra;
    }
    public delegate IntPtr KeyboardLowLevelProc(int hCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    public IntPtr KeyboardLowLevelCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0) {
            KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbd = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            if (kbd.key == Keys.D0 && blockD0) {                
                if(ModifierKeys == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift)) {
                    SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");
                    //Add custom code as the response to Ctrl + Shift + D0 here
                    //....
                }
                return new IntPtr(1);//Discard the default behavior
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }
    bool blockD0;
    KeyboardLowLevelProc proc; //this should be declared in the form scope
    IntPtr hHook;
    //your Form1 constructor
    public Form1(){
       InitializeComponent();
       //Get current module Handle
       IntPtr currentModuleHandle = GetModuleHandle(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName);
       //Set the keyboard hook
       hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, proc, currentModuleHandle, 0);//WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13
       //register these Key events for your richTextBox1 
       richTextBox1.KeyDown += (s, e) => {
            if(e.KeyCode != Keys.D0) blockD0 = true;
       };
       richTextBox1.KeyUp += (s, e) => {
            if (ModifierKeys == Keys.None) blockD0 = false;
       };
       //Unhook keyboard when form is closed
       FormClosed += (s,e) => {
          if (hHook != IntPtr.Zero) {
              UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
              hHook = IntPtr.Zero;
          }
       }
    }
```

**A little about the explanation**: I do not understand exactly why we have to use `Global Low-level Keyboard hook` here, I guess that when the keys combination `Ctrl + Shift + D0` is pressed, **there may be some key message cloned and dispatched to another thread**, that's why all the **manual interceptions** in the current thread can't intercept or override the `Ctrl + Shift + D0`, however the `global low-level keyboard hook` can handle the `key messages` in **all threads** of the current module and it can intercept any key messages.

I mentioned about the `beep sound` problem, if you want to experience it, just remove the `SendKeys.Send("{ESC}");`, in fact you can try some other keys like `1`, `2`, ... they also make the keys combination `Ctrl + Shift + ...` valid and help avoid any `beep sound`.

### UPDATE

The solution above works OK, it's the best solution with the point that the `Ctrl + Shift + D0` should be discarded **cleanly and totally**. However it's a little long (as you can see). I've found that when you press the `Ctrl + Shift + D0`, the message `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST` is sent, this message causes the behavior which you don't want. So we can try another solution, with `PreProcessMessage` you can still catch the combination `Ctrl + Shift + D0` but you just can't discard it (because it's dispatched to another thread), that means you can add your own code there, instead of discarding the `Ctrl + Shift + D0`, we can discard the effect/behavior it causes instead by discarding the message `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`. We have the following code:

```
//Create a custom RichTextBox class
public class CustomRichTextBox : RichTextBox {
   protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
     if(m.Msg == 0x50) return; //WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST = 0x50
     base.WndProc(ref m);
   }
   public override bool PreProcessMessage(ref Message msg) {            
        if (msg.Msg == 0x100)//WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100
        {
           Keys keyData = (Keys)msg.WParam | ModifierKeys;
           if(keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.D0)){
             //your own code goes here...
           }
        }
        return base.PreProcessMessage(ref msg);
   }
}
```

You can see that the second approach is much shorter, however as I said, it doesn't **actually** suppress the `Ctrl + Shift + D0`, it just suppresses the default behavior caused by the message `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`. I guess it's enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts.  One thing I didn't think to try was Spy++ or some way to examine messages generated.  Good call.  I do prefer the simpler approach and will likely use it.  However, did you try `keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.D0)`?  For me, like I said in the question, keyData never actually contains those values.  However, perhaps it's safe to simply put my replacement behaviour where and when WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST is detected.

Comment: @CraigSilver of course the `keyData` you find in `MouseDown` or `PreProcessMessage` won't be so, but that `keyData` is just a variable assigned to `(Keys)msg.WParam | ModifierKeys;`, so its value can be `(Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.D0)`, the `ModifierKeys` is the trick here, its value can be used together with the actual `keyData`.