# Why does Ctrl+Shift+D0 not trigger KeyDown ...and what can I do about it?

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I'm listening to `FrameworkElement.KeyDown` events and am trying to catch [Ctrl][Shift][0].

This must be some "special" combination in some ways, because the event fires for every combination of these three keys, but, if I press [Ctrl], then [Shift] (in either order) and then [0] (=`Key.D0`) the event fires for the first two keys, but not for the last one, when all of them are pressed together.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556221/how-do-i-override-ctrlshift0-zero-for-winforms-richtextbox), and it mentions something about `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST`, but I don't understand what *that* is (nothing happens on my system when I press the combination); and the proposed solution there doesn't help me, because it doesn't apply to a `FrameworkElement` - and I need it in the `KeyDown` handler ...if possible.

Currently, I'm settling for [Shift]+[0]... :o/

Comment: https://excelatfinance.com/xlf18/xlf-change-key-sequence.php ... [Google'd](https://www.google.com/search?q=ctrl+shift+0)

Comment: It could be this: https://superuser.com/a/1455798/99869

Comment: @madreflection OMG! That is so shocking (and something I have/want no control over on customer machines) that I'll stick with [Shift]+[0]... Thanks, though!